# Reboot when uninstaling the application LG G4

Tags: applications, reboot, uninstallation, lg-g4

my LG G4 have a problem with updating software and deleting applications.

Everytime I want to delete an application, system throws me an error

com.android.settings was stopped

I can not get even into application settings...

also, when I want to upgrade OS, files are downloaded but once phone is restarted, I got an "Error" without detail informations about error....

I've tryed to execute this

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.settings
```

but it just reboot my phone. No changes.

Have you ever faced same problem ? ... It's a bit anoying, being unable to delete application

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed any custom software on your phone recently? If so than that could explain some issues. First of all the bugs you are experiencing with the settings, but also when trying to update the phone. Many of the custom versions of Android do not support the OTA (Over the Air) updates.

However, if you do have stock version of Android there could be numerous issues. My recommendation would be to backup all of your files and simply restore your phone. Sometimes this can resolve any internal issue that Android is experiencing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
I've just got the phone and yes, it might have custom software, despite everything looks like original one. 
I've installed the application - root checker and it's didn't shows that root has been made..., so I'm bit in doubts.

I would like to reinstall everything to the original, factory state, but I'm afraid that simple restoring will not help as I've already did that.

I don't mind to have phone rooted, but I would like to have everything under control... can you please help me how to get the original software back ? Thank you

Comment: Well in theory, when u install a new rom, it doesn't really have to have root. Sometimes upon installing a new rom you need to root your phone again (for some roms, others may keep root). If you don't believe you have a stock rom it is really best you install it yourself, as you can never be sure what you got and what that rom actually does.

Usually a good place to start is LG's official website. If you cannot find it there look on this link: https://forum.xda-developers.com/g4 Here you will find some factory and many custom roms. As this page is for developers it should be safe. Goodluck!